# Read a TCP Message

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, client

I have a problem with TCP Connection (I've made a class extends Thread).I've implemented the read part with this code:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];


             StringBuilder reader = new StringBuilder();

             int numRead = 0;
             if ((numRead = socket.getInputStream().read(bytes)) >= 0)
             {
               reader.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
             }
```

this is the only code working for my app. Yesterday I wrote this code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
BufferedReader(socket.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String msg;
while(msg=in.readLine() != null) //I also tried while (msg != "")  
{
 str.append(msg);
} 
Log.d("String:",str.toString();
```

But it didn't work for me: it didn't print anything. 
So I also tried code without while cycle, and it didn't work too.

How can I change it? I need to listen the sequence of message from my server, for example:

- *HELLO FROM SERVER*
- *NOW I'M SENDING DATA*
- *THIS IS THE MESSAGE BEFORE POSITION*
- *position in a special code*
- etc.

how I need to change from my code?
Thank you

Comment: Refer :http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: I read this link...but I don't understand these 2 lines:
String read = input.readLine();
updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readLine()` only returns null at end of stream: that is to say, when the peer closes the connection.

Probably you should be reading and writing a line at a time, but it's your application protocol: only you really know.

Comment: I send a request to server, for example "HELLO" and it answers me a sequence of Strings, some of this not in the same period of time...for example I send: "HELLO", server send me "HELLO_YOU", after 10 second it send me "REQUEST_COMPLETE", after 30 second it send me "12345", etc...

Comment: If the client wants to read lines using readLine() the server should send lines. So send "HELLO_YOU\n".

Comment: I solved the problem! Server doesn't send \n so I use the simple function read(). Thank you!